Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified
i ma getting this error everytime installing python but PIP is not workinhg
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python project> pip --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.


What is pip?  Is it a custom command alias in your shell?  Show us the output of where.exe pip

Try pip3 instead.
